# Postgres: count value from column which has highest count

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, highest

I have a table as below

```
IDnumber     ProcessID
  1            21
  2            22
  3            21
  4            21
  5            22
  6            22
  7            22
  8            22
  9            23
```

Now I have a query as below

```
select count(*) filter (where ProcessID IN (21, 22)) FROM table
```

This query will give output = 8 which is correct.

However, I need a query to find the count of only that column which is highest between the provided list of columns in where condition.

In the above example '22' occurs 5 times hence it is higher than '21' which occurs 3 times.

Is there any function/logic to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you can use aggregation and `limit`:

```
select processid, count(*)
from t
where ProcessID in (21, 22)
group by processid
order by count(*)
limit 1;
```

Note that this returns one row, even when there are ties.  If you want all the rows with ties, you can use window functions:

```
select p.*
from (select processid, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where ProcessID in (21, 22)
      group by processid
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

You could also combine this on row:

```
select array_agg(processid), cnt
from (select processid, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      where ProcessID in (21, 22)
      group by processid
     ) p
group by cnt
order by cnt desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like

```
 with cte as
 (select count(*) as cnt,ProcessID
 FROM table where ProcessID IN (21, 22)
 group by ProcessID
 ) select max(cnt) from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

First u need to group by the provided list and than used that as the table

```
Select a.ProcessID,MAX(a.Cnt) 
from (
Select ProcessID,count(*) as Cnt  
from table where ProcessID IN (21,22) 
group by ProcessID order by Count(*) DESC) a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER()
FROM tablename
WHERE ProcessID IN (21, 22)
GROUP BY ProcessID
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pmNDhD5XVP391eM48nPBaD/0).